# Does SLURM submission scripts run on the compute node or the controller machine?

Tags: slurm

I'm getting started with Slurm and I was assuming that the submission script I pass to `sbatch` runs on the controller and the steps that are marked with `srun` will run as a job *step* on a compute node. Consider example below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 12
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --job-name=hello

hostname
srun hostname
```

I was expecting to see the hostname of the machine I'm submitting from first followed by the name of the compute node that's allocated for the job. Instead it seems the whole script is run on the compute node. I see the compute node's hostname in the log and then it fails because it can't find `srun` on that node:

`/var/spool/slurm/d/job00201/slurm_script: line 5: srun: command not found`

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Submission scripts run on compute nodes. `srun` should be available in the compute nodes, if it is not, talk to your system administrator. The expected output for your script would be two times the name of the compute host assigned to that job.

Comment: Interesting. I thought installing `slurmd` package (in Debian) on compute node is enough. How do I get those extra binaries? Are they in a separate package?

Comment: I think I need `slurm-client` package on Debian

Comment: I have no idea. This would be a question for sysadmins, not for programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out installing `slurmd` on the compute node is not enough. Installing `slurm-client` package pulls all those `s` binaries